# PC reboots when shutdown, only when "Legacy USB 3.0 Support" is enabled

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, shutdown

I have Ubuntu and Windows 10 in dualboot (ASRock Z97 Extreme4 Motherboard), a fresh install with nothing installed on either operating system. When shutting down from either OS, the computer reboots a couple of seconds after shutting down.

However, I found that disabling "Legacy USB 3.0 Support" fixes this issue. It does however introduce another issue: now I cannot use my keyboard before fully booting into Ubuntu. In other words, I cannot access the BIOS or use the GRUB menu. Once Ubuntu has booted up I can use the keyboard again.

I have since re-enabled "Legacy USB 3.0 Support" so I can get into the BIOS, but I would like to find a way to shut the PC down without disabling USB 3.0 or finding another way for my keyboard to work without it.

Comment: Odd the keyboard should only require USB 1.1 or 2 at the highest. You don't have a USB 2 port on the motherboard you can plug it into?

Comment: The motherboard does have USB 2 ports, but with Legacy USB 3.0 Support enabled those also don't work for my keyboard (as well as the 3.0 ports not working).

Comment: The USB 2 ports should always work normally... Strange.

Comment: Check the manufacturer's site for a firmware update (they may call it a "BIOS update" or "UEFI update"). If one is available, apply it and try again.

Comment: Intel USB 3.0 Mode" from "Smart Auto" to "Disabled" means that you disable usb3.0 support. The best solution (that keeps some usb 3 support) is to change the intel usb 3.0 setting from `smart auto` to `auto` and Legacy USB 3.0 Support to `disabled`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out the fix: switch "Intel USB 3.0 Mode" from "Smart Auto" to "Disabled". Then I can shut down the computer while being able to use the keyboard during boot when it boots up again.